# Div placed over and relative to fullscreen-img

Tags: html, css

How do I place a div over **and** relative to an fullscreen-img? I want the div to be on the same place relative to the image even when the window is resized.

**EDIT:**

It almost works now. I positioned my div to an outer div instead of the image. The problem is that the outer div need to have a specified size (% or px), else the relative-div won't know where to position. When I use 100% x 100% on the outer div, it's not the same height as the image. The image is fullscreen and should work when the window is resized.

```
<div id="outer-div" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;">
    <img  id="fullscreen-image" src="image.jpg" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="relative-div" style="position:relative; background-color:#000; bottom:20%; left:50%; width:30px; height:30px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code or what you tryed..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This works when using `absolute` positioning -

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/5rjgetq0/1/

This will work event if the `img` is not `absolute`, but there should be a warapping div with `position:relative` to find the `top` and `left` position of the image.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enought: it's a fullscreen-image.

Answer (score 0):

Plase check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/5rjgetq0/3/

test with different `height` for the image.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work if you flatten the window height. Also the image is dragged out..

Comment: It should work like Google maps. Names on the same spot even when the map changes size. However, I got it working now and next time I ask a question will be a bit more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working (I positioned my div to an outer div instead of the image):

```
<div id="outer-div" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
    <img id="fullscreen-image" src="image.jpg" style="width:100%; z-index:-10; bottom:0; left:0;">
    <div style="background-color:#000; bottom:20%; left:50%; width:30px; height:30px; position:relative;"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery (changes height of 'outer-div' when 'fullscreen-image' changes size):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //Runs once after document ready
    $('#outer-div').css({'height':$('#fullscreen-image').height()});
});
$(window).resize(function() { //Runs when window is resized
    $('#outer-div').css({'height':$('#fullscreen-image').height()});
});
```

I know this is not the best solution so if you come up with a css-only solution you're welcome to post it.

Comment: i posted the solution to place it relative to the image. that is what you had asked for